# Why don't you recover the bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

There are some questions about what happens with the bounty if there is no extra answer after offering the extra reputation. The answer is the reputation simply expires. My question is why. I mean, If you get some answers, it seems me fair the most up-voted answer gets the bounty, even if it is not your desired answer. But, why when you don't receive any answer the reputation must expire? It' is not right. Some users (including myself) have to ''fight'' very hard to get its reputation. When they actually need an answer they offer a bounty because they really want a solution. But if this solution never comes, why have they to loose their reputation?

Comment: As explained elsewhere.  You pay the bounty to get extra exposure for the question.  Similarly, when a business advertises in a newspaper, they have to pay for the ad even if no one comes to their store as a result.

Comment: @GEdgar: Humm... nice comparison. In my opinion this site should work in a different way, but anyway, very good comment. However, in a store, you pay to the newspaper. That means clients don't take any profit. Here they do, because the best answer gets the bounty.

Comment: I certainly hope that you read [what Help Center has to say about bounties](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) before you decided to start one. Particularly the part where it written in bold that the bounty is **non-refundable under any circumstances**. The answers to any other questions can be found from one of meta-threads carrying [the appropriate tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bounty).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I had already read the help center. And it doesn't explain why. That is my question.

Comment: Why? The softworks that way, and cannot be argued with. More and better reasons for this implementation choice are given in the other questions with this tag (that you could/should have studied before posting).

Comment: I have read some questions tagged with 'bounty' and I haven't seen any answer. But if you think my question has answer mark it as duplicated. I don't think so.